# Is there a way to uncompress .Z files using php?

Tags: php, compression

Is there a way to uncompress .Z files using php?

Comment: Depends on what compression algorithm is used, where does the file come from? If it's just a Zip file with another extension you should be able to unzip it with http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Comment: Thanks Chris R, I have tried that, but it didn't work... (it did for .zip files)... Some info on the file i am trying to uncompress: The Z extension is a Unix zip file, a pre-cursor to gz and tar, but still in common use in Unix environments – any ideas if this is possible to uncompress with php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays `uncompress` is just nothing more than a one-liner invoking `gzip` with proper options. To use `gzip`, you don't have execute shell. You can use [Zlib extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php) instead. I'd try something like:

```
<?php
$contents = zlib_decode(file_get_contents('/path/file.Z'));
```

Comment: Thanks Vartec for your response, I don't appear to be able to access the Zlib extention on my version of php... is there any other work around other than ChrisR suggestion?

Comment: @jon: if you cannot access zlib, there isn't. FYI, `uncompress ` is equivalent to `gzip -d`.

Comment: I didn't complete understand your response about uncompress, however between you, ChrisR and google I have found a solution that works on my server: shell_exec("gunzip $file"); thanks for your help. Regards J

Comment: @jon: I've meant, that `shell_exec("uncompres $file")` is same as `shell_exec("gzip -d $file")`, which as you well noted is same as `shell_exec("gunzip $file")`

Comment: The anonymous edit, "So that beginner users can see whether or not their code was successful, it's important to show them to use `var_dump()` and not `echo($contents)`--it's generally important to show users how to check for success; so, I hope this change can stay applied." should have been a comment instead.

Answer (score 1):

After searching some i've found that .z files are files that were compressed using the `compress` program. If your php installation allows `shell_exec` and your webserver is running unix/linux you could run the `uncompress` program on your server. This is the (untested) idea:

```
<?php
$file = '/tmp/archive.z';
shell_exec("uncompress $file");
```

Comment: Thanks Chris I will take a look at that, but I don't think I can do that on my server.

Comment: Thanks ChrisR - this worked for me: shell_exec("gunzip $file");