# Uncompress *.Z file in PHP

Tags: php, lzw

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to uncompress .Z files using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174917/is-there-a-way-to-uncompress-z-files-using-php)

Looking for any leads or suggestions for a function in PHP that will uncompress a Unix .Z  file in a Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

The [php-lzw](http://code.google.com/p/php-lzw/) project looks like it should meet your needs:

> LZW is a simple algorithm efficient mainly in text compression. This library provides simple functions for LZW compression and decompression.

Comment: [Link only answers are discouraged!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) Please write a full answer, instead of just providing a link.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know. I wanted to underline the googleability of the answer; I should have limited myself to a comment. Thanks for the advice to both! (*and now I know also I can't upvote two comments in less than five seconds* :-))